# Quadrature formula for singular integrals over rectangular cuboids

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-optimization

A)Find the maximum of the following :
$$\int_{\Omega_{a,b,c}}\int_{\Omega_{a,b,c}}\frac{dV(X)dV(Y)}{\|X-Y\|^2}$$
where ${\Omega_{a,b,c}}=[0,a]\times[0,b]\times[0,c]$, given $abc=1$ with $a,b,c>0$.

B)Is there a quadrature formula for singular integrals over rectangular cuboids?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding A: Have you tried a numerical evaluation to get an idea of your integral as function of $a$ and $b$?

If you want to do so, the section 2 of the following publication of Lloyd N. Trefethen might be helpful: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/2011_137.pdf.

The author shows how to calculate efficiently singular integrals which are of same kind as your six-dimensional integral (but with exponent 3).

Comment: I looked at Treftethen's paper. Very interesting and slightly shocking(to me).  never would have thought that a closed form of gravitational potential of cubes is not known. Although the one I came across with is in fact the squared of Newtonian. After all I not greedy and If could prove that the maximizer is a=b=1, I will be on cloud nine.